# Limit involving average of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Random variables $X_1,X_2,...$ are independent and $P(X_i=1)=p,\,P(X_i=0)=1-p$, $0<p<1$.
For $t\in\mathbb{R}$ check whether the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty}P\left(\frac{X_1+...+X_n}n>t\right)$$ exist.
Any hints?

Comment: Hint: consider the cases $t<p,t=p,t>p$. The first and last ones are easy, the middle one is slightly more difficult.

Comment: Hint: $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n X_k \sim Bin(n,p)$. We have $\mathbb P( S_n > tn) = 1 - \mathbb P(S_n \le tn) = 1 - \mathbb P (\frac{S_n - np}{\sqrt{npq}} \le \sqrt{n} \frac{t-p}{\sqrt{pq}})$. Now, consider @Ian hint, and try to modify de Moivre-Laplace's theorem.

Comment: @DominikKutek Part of the point of the case work is that you actually don't even need to set up to use the central limit theorem except when $t=p$.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use CLT, you just need to check how variation behaves while taking average. Your statement is true for every sufficiently well-behaving random variables :)

Check variation of the expression $\frac{X_1 + \ldots + X_n}{n}$ and then apply https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality

Comment: To handle $t=p$ you need CLT, since this case is essentially asking how the probability to be in $(p-\epsilon,p)$ compares to the probability to be in $(p,p+\epsilon)$. WLLN cannot answer this, it can only say that together these two intervals asymptotically take up all the probability mass together.